# How to use nokogiri to select element after a specified element?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

take the following table for example, I know how to match `<td>'Title_A'</td>` by xapth's text() function, is there any straight forward way to select the `<td> text_unknown </td>` after it? :

```
<table>
    <tr><td rowspan=2> Title_A </td>    <td> text_unknown </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> text_unknown </td></tr>

    <tr><td rowspan=2> Title_B </td>    <td> text_unknown </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> text_unknown </td></tr>

    <tr><td rowspan=4> Title_C </td>    <td> text_unknown </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> text_unknown </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> text_unknown </td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> text_unknown </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @MarkThomas, I use `xpath('//table/tr/td[text()="Title_A"]'` to select the title `td`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you are matching 'Title_A' with the following XPath:

```
//td[text()='Title_A']
```

The next cell would be

```
//td[text()='Title_A']/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Alternatively, if you already have the title cell in a variable:

```
title_a = doc.xpath("//td[text()='Title_A']")
```

Then you can use the DOM method `next_sibling`:

```
next_cell = title_a.next_sibling
```

Comment: Thanks @MarkThomas, the next_sibling method works. But I missed some `<tr>` in the question, to select all the following `<td>` I use the `rowspan` value to loop and extract what I need. Is it possible to select certain number of items using xpath? Thanks again. :)

Comment: So you want the 2nd column after the title, but the first column of each subsequent row until you get to the next titled row?

Comment: Yes! It seems impossible to have a xpath matcher automatically detect this logic though, but it would be great if I could specify how many items I want in the matcher. I wish to utilize method like `each` instead of C fashion for-loop which I am using now.

Comment: I don't think it's impossible, but it would be a bit more complicated. It would be simpler to iterate over rows and keep appending cell text (e.g. using the titles as a hash key).

Answer (score 0):

Use css for html and xpath for xml. `+` is the css next adjacent sibling selector.

```
doc.at('td[text()="Title_A"] + td')
```

I see some spaces around Title_A though, so maybe:

```
doc.at('td[text()*="Title_A"] + td')
```

Comment: Hi @pguardiario, the css style looks awesome! Is it possible to select more than one `td` at one time? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking for, maybe you want the general sibling selector `~`, You should probably take some time to get familiar with css if you aren't already.